# Djikstra's shortest path issues

Tags: java, graph, shortest-path

This is an algorithm question more than coding.. but I have an implementation of Djikstra's algorithm that seems to work for most graphs but appears to give the wrong output for large graphs with many equal edge lengths. I am unable to debug it because I am not able to come up with any small input where it fails. Any thoughts on how to approach this issue? The key function is below. The algorithm I am using (and maybe this is incorrect) is:

0)    Divide the graph into conquered and unconquered sets. Init a min Heap.

1)    Start with starting vertex (S) in conquered and everything else in unconq

2)    Put all the edges from conq -> unconq in the heap.

3)    Get the min edge(s). If tied, for each min edge update dist and move vertices involved from unconquered to conquered.

4)    Go to 2 while unconquered is not empty.

5)    At this step all edges are conquered.

I implemented this and it mostly works - frustratingly fails for large inputs where there are lots of edges with equal weights and the really frustrating part is that my output matches the correct output to a large extent, only a few distances are calculated wrongly. I am pretty sure this problem has to do with edges of equal weight. Any thoughts?

```
public int shortestDjikstra() {
    int vertex;
    GenericHeap<Edge> gHeap = new GenericHeap<Edge>();
    Set<Integer> unConquered = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> conquered = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        if (i != S) {
            unConquered.add(i);
            dist[i] = INFINITY;
        }
    }
    vertex = S;
    conquered.add(S);
    Edge[] eList = getEdges(conquered, unConquered);            
    while (unConquered.size() > 0) {
        for (Edge e: eList) {
            assert(e.w != INFINITY);
            gHeap.add(e);
            Integer a[] = e.getEdge();
            updateDist(a[0] ,a[1], e.w);
        }    
        Edge e = gHeap.getMin();
        Set<Integer> verticesToRemove = new HashSet<Integer>();
        while (e != null) {
            Integer a[] = e.getEdge();
            int v2;
            vertex = a[1];
            v2 = a[0]; 
            if (unConquered.contains(a[0])) {
                verticesToRemove.add(a[0]);                   
            } 
            if (unConquered.contains(a[1])) {
                verticesToRemove.add(a[1]);
            }
            updateDist(vertex, v2, e.w);
            e = gHeap.getMinRepeats(e);
        }
        if (verticesToRemove.size() == 0) break;
        for (int v:verticesToRemove) {
            unConquered.remove(v);
        }
        eList = getEdges(verticesToRemove, unConquered);
    }

    printDistList("Final: ");
    return -1;
}
```